# Can static_cast work for bit fields?

Tags: c++

Hi does static cast work for bit fields?. Because here i have created a bit field of 32 bit Long data and i am trying to cast it to u32.

```
void CO2_SpiDriver::CreateBuffer() {
    //#[ operation CreateBuffer()
    typedef struct scr_t
     {
         union {
            u32 data;
             struct {
                 u8 CRC : 4; 
                 u16 Datatosend : 16;
                 u8 DataLengthCode : 2;
                 u8 AddressReg : 4;
                 u8 ReadandWrite : 1;
                 u8 InstrucCode : 3;
                 u8 ExtChipId : 2;
             };
         };
     } scr_t;  

     //set of data bits
     scr_t se;
     se.CRC = 0x00;   //CRC BITS 0 to 3
     se.Datatosend = 0x0000000000000000;  //Data bits 19 to 4
     se.DataLengthCode = 0x00; //DLC bits 21 and 20
     se.AddressReg = 0x00;     // SMP580 registers to access 25-22
     se.ReadandWrite = 0x01;  //Read|Write Reg 26
     se.InstrucCode = 0x5;    //InstrCode 29-27
     se.ExtChipId = 0x2;      //ExtChipId 31-30       

     static_cast<u32>(se)
```

But here i am getting an error that scr_t cannot be casted to u32. Can anyone give some suggestions

Comment: *correction* static_cast<u32>(se)

Comment: `static_cast` works only for _related_ types.

Comment: `se.data` is already an `u32`.

Comment: i would want to cast the struct...(bit field)

Comment: Replace `static_cast<u32>(data)`  with `se.data`. You don't need the `typedef` in C++. I can't remember if the anonymous `struct` is valid there.

Comment: hi @jarod32 thank you i would do that next time :)

Comment: but then you read the non active union member -> UB.

Comment: okay.. is there a way to get this bit field as a 32 bit Long data?... i understand that static cast works for related types. i also have a way to set and clear a bit, but i would not want to use that. That is why i tried a different Approach of bit field, but casting it seems to be an issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++, only one of the fields of an union is active at any time. The only portable way to reinterpret a memory layout is to use `std::memcpy`:

```
struct bf {
    u8 CRC : 4; 
    u16 Datatosend : 16;
    u8 DataLengthCode : 2;
    u8 AddressReg : 4;
    u8 ReadandWrite : 1;
    u8 InstrucCode : 3;
    u8 ExtChipId : 2;
};

bf se;
se.CRC = 0x00;   //CRC BITS 0 to 3
se.Datatosend = 0x0000000000000000;  //Data bits 19 to 4
se.DataLengthCode = 0x00; //DLC bits 21 and 20
se.AddressReg = 0x00;     // SMP580 registers to access 25-22
se.ReadandWrite = 0x01;  //Read|Write Reg 26
se.InstrucCode = 0x5;    //InstrCode 29-27
se.ExtChipId = 0x2;      //ExtChipId 31-30  

u32 se_as_u32;
static_assert(sizeof(se_as_u32) <= sizeof(se), "UB detector"); // avoid reading buffer overflow (see explanation below)
std::memcpy(&se_as_u32, &se, sizeof(se_as_u32));
```

---

Note: I've added the line

```
static_assert(sizeof(se_as_u32) <= sizeof(se), "UB detector");
```

in order to protect `se` to be read outside of its "bounds":

```
std::memcpy(&se_as_u32, &se, sizeof(se_as_u32));
```

This reads `sizeof(u32)` (probably 4) bytes from `se`. In the eventuality that `se` was smaller than 4 bytes long, `memcpy` would read "outside of it", this is a kind of buffer overflow and result in undefined behaviour (this is bad).
In the case where the inequality was not respected (`sizeof(se_as_u32) > sizeof(se)`), a merciful `abort()` would be called and the program would promptly crash instead of maybe working for a time and destroy the production one day.

Comment: For "portable" as in "portable using only the Holy ISO Standard's guarantees, disregarding actual compilers, or conflating them all with g++".

Comment: In C++20 there will be `bit_cast` from the new `<bit>` header, to avoid the verbosity of `memcpy()` and maybe exploit more compiler intrinsics.

Comment: There's a difference between theory and practice. The non-discriminated `union` language feature makes no sense with the C++ standard's formal rules. Many compilers support the original intent.

Comment: @underscore_d don't worry, `std::memcpy` is almost always a compiler specific builtin ;)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf And OP's specific compiler being?

Comment: @YSC Probably, and we already know that compilers can optimise a call to `memcpy()` into pure reinterpretation without actually copying any bytes - while making the code well-formed unlike writing a reinterpreting cast or using a `union` - but either way, `bit_cast` will convey intent more clearly.

Comment: About [`std::bit_cast`, see it's proposal on open-std.org](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0476r2.html). It's not yet guaranteed to make it to C++20.

Comment: Hi @Ysc thank you, but this line   static_assert(sizeof(se_as_u32) <= sizeof(se));  does not seem, to work

Comment: could you explain me about that line of code... static_assert(sizeof(se_as_u32) <= sizeof(se)); .... I did not quite get this ...well my error there is expected a string literal..... while se is an obj...

Comment: Hi @YSC thank you for taking your time and explaing, but here my sizeof(se_as_u32) = 4 and sizeof(se) is 6.... so i dont know if this works

Comment: The size of se is greater than se_u32 ,.. that s something which is giving me a hitch

Comment: And this is why this answer is correct: you have found out at compile time, with a static_assert failure, that your compiler is laying your struct out differently to what you imagine, rather than at runtime, with some horrible symptom of UB

Comment: yes it is a good Approach.. but i have a CRC of 4 bits and ist mappled to 8 Byte of data. and remaininf 4 is empty and ist mapped to one particular loaction.. i dont know if using bit field is the correct Approach here

Comment: And the Memory address ist mapped to is 0x00000C00 ehich is a wrong value

Comment: @underscore_d - Can you give an example with bit_cast for the same question

Comment: @underscore_d - no need. I just figured out and its simple and easy with bit_cast.